# How can I manipulate a nested QJsonObject/QJsonArray structure in c++ with minimal code?

Tags: qt, qml

Say I have a nested QJsonObject that looks like the following JSON:

```
var sample_set_ = 
  {child_sample_set_objs:[
    {sample_containers:[
      {"samples":[
        {id:1, sample_val:42}
      ]}
    ]}
  ]}
```

or equivalently:

```
auto sample_set_ = 
  QJsonObject{
    {"child_sample_set_objs",
      QJsonArray{
        { QJsonObject{
          {"sample_containers",
            QJsonArray{
              { QJsonObject{
                {"samples,
                  QJsonArray{
                    { QJsonObject{
                      "id", 1,
                      "sample_val", 42
                    } }
                  }
                }
              }
            } }
          }
        } }
      }
    }
  }
```

How can I write the data to the leaf node and mutate `sample_set_` without copying back all the way up the structure?

The following is what I believe I need to do and it is horrendously verbose.

Given `int child_ss_idx` and `int sample_container_idx`:

```
auto child_sample_set_objs = sample_set_["child_sample_set_objs"].toArray();
auto child_ss = child_sample_set_objs[child_ss_idx].toObject();
auto sample_containers = child_ss["sample_containers"].toArray();
auto sample_container = sample_containers[sample_container_idx].toObject();
auto samples = sample_container["samples"].toArray();

// the write vvvvvvvv
samples.push_back(QJsonObject{ {"sample_set_id", child_ss["id"]} });

sample_container["samples"] = samples;
sample_containers[sample_container_idx] = sample_container;
child_ss["sample_containers"] = sample_containers;
child_sample_set_objs[child_ss_idx] = child_ss;
sample_set_["child_sample_set_objs"] = child_sample_set_objs;
```

Comment: Have some JSON document template as a string and modify the resulting QJsonDocumet/QJsonObject? You have to have some template to start with. When needed, find the desired node and then modify/delete/insert.

Comment: And if that JSON update is quite routine you just have that template JSON be like `"{{"token1", %1}, {"token2", %2}}"` to quickly format with `QString::arg()` etc.

Comment: The best way I've found to manipulate the QML UI and instantiate things that are of a variable nature is through giving QML a QJsonObject or QJsonArray and then using repeaters or listviews to stamp out the appropriate widgets.  My data is coming from SQLite through a C++ helper that then formats the data into a QJsonObjects and gives it to QML to traverse through the data tree.